# Unable to book e ticket on irctc desptite having login

Tags: trains, online-resources, tickets, india, indian-railways

I just created a login for IRCTC and when i actually tried to book a ticket, it only gives me one option as "i-ticket" under ticket type. I am unablet to book tickets as the drop down under ticket type gives only i-ticket option, and does not give e-ticket option.

Please help.

Comment: Have you considered contacting IRCTC? It sounds like you're having a problem with their site.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot ? I have booked numerous times and and have both options. Normally I take e ticket .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with a website, not a travel question.

Comment: @Ramsun The problem has been corrected now. You should see the e-ticket option in IRCTC website. If you still cannot do it, better download an app. It is also available for windows PC.